# Collision Detection in a List

Tags: python, list, tkinter, collision-detection

I'm new to collision detection and have been working on a brick breaker style game with Tkinter. Each of my bricks are created separately so instead of creating if statements for each of the 30+ bricks I put them in a list, however when I run the program the collision detection function doesn't work. Can someone please help I don't understand what is wrong in the code.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
drawpad = Canvas(root, width=600,height=600, background='white')
player = drawpad.create_rectangle(260,590,340,595, fill = "blue")
ball = drawpad.create_oval(293,576,307,590, fill = "white")
brick1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,20,80,50, fill='green')
brick2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,100,80,130, fill='green')
brick3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(30,180,80,210, fill='green')
brick4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,20,150,50, fill='green')
brick5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,100,150,130, fill='green')
brick6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(100,180,150,210, fill='green')
brick7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,20,220,50, fill='green')
brick8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,100,220,130, fill='green')
brick9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(170,180,220,210, fill='green')
brick10= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,20,290,50, fill='green')
brick11= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,100,290,130, fill='green')
brick12= drawpad.create_rectangle(240,180,290,210, fill='green')
brick13= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,20,360,50, fill='green')
brick14= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,100,360,130, fill='green')
brick15= drawpad.create_rectangle(310,180,360,210, fill='green')
brick16= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,20,430,50, fill='green')
brick17= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,100,430,130, fill='green')
brick18= drawpad.create_rectangle(380,180,430,210, fill='green')
brick19= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,20,500,50, fill='green')
brick20= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,100,500,130, fill='green')
brick21= drawpad.create_rectangle(450,180,500,210, fill='green')
brick22= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,20,570,50, fill='green')
brick23= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,100,570,130, fill='green')
brick24= drawpad.create_rectangle(520,180,570,210, fill='green')
brickA1 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,60,110,90, fill='cyan')
brickA2 = drawpad.create_rectangle(60,140,110,170, fill='cyan')
brickA3 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,60,180,90, fill='cyan')
brickA4 = drawpad.create_rectangle(130,140,180,170, fill='cyan')
brickA5 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,60,250,90, fill='cyan')
brickA6 = drawpad.create_rectangle(200,140,250,170, fill='cyan')
brickA7 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,60,320,90, fill='cyan')
brickA8 = drawpad.create_rectangle(270,140,320,170, fill='cyan')
brickA9 = drawpad.create_rectangle(340,60,390,90, fill='cyan')
brickA10= drawpad.create_rectangle(340,140,390,170, fill='cyan')
brickA11= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,60,460,90, fill='cyan')
brickA12= drawpad.create_rectangle(410,140,460,170, fill='cyan')
brickA13= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,60,530,90, fill='cyan')
brickA14= drawpad.create_rectangle(480,140,530,170, fill='cyan')
bricklist =[brick1,brick2,brick3,brick4,brick5,brick6,brick7,brick8,brick9,brick10,brick11,brick12,brick13,brick14,brick15,brick16,brick17,brick18,brick19,brick20,brick21,brick22,brick23,brick24,brickA1,brickA2,brickA3,brickA4,brickA5,brickA6,brickA7,brickA8,brickA9,brickA10,brickA11,brickA12,brickA13,brickA14]
direction = 0
import random
randAngle = 0
angle = 0

class myApp(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        global drawpad
        self.myParent = parent  
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        self.myContainer1.pack()
        # Score
        self.prompt = "Score:"

        self.label1 = Label(root, text=self.prompt, width=len(self.prompt), bg='green')
        self.label1.pack()

        self.score = 0

        self.scoreTxt = Label(root, text=str(self.score), width=len(str(self.score)), bg='green')
        self.scoreTxt.pack()

        drawpad.pack()
        root.bind_all('<Key>', self.key)
        self.animate()

    def animate(self):
        global drawpad
        global ball
        global direction
        global angle
        global randAngle
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if y1 <= 0:
            direction = 5
        elif x1 >= px1 and x2 <= px2 and y2 >= py1:
            direction = -5
            randAngle = random.randint(0,12)
            angle = randAngle - 6
        elif x1 <= 0 and y2 <= 600 or x2 >= 600 and y2 <= 600:
            angle = -angle

        didWeHit = self.collisionDetect()
        if didWeHit == True:
            if (x1 >= bx1 and x2 <=bx2 and y1 >= by2) or (x1 >= bx1 and x2 <=bx2 and y2 <= by1):
                direction = -direction
            if (x1 >= bx1 and y2 <= by1 and y1 >= by2) or (x2 <=bx2 and y1 >= by2 and y2 <= by1):
                angle = -angle
            didWeHit = False

        drawpad.move(ball, angle, direction)
        drawpad.after(5,self.animate)


    def key(self,event):
        global drawpad
        global player
        global ball
        global direction
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        px1,py1,px2,py2 = drawpad.coords(player)
        if event.char == " ":
            direction = -5
        if event.char == "a":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px1 > 0:
                    drawpad.move(player,-8,0)
        if event.char == "d":
            if x1 != 293 and y1 != 576 and x2 != 307 and y2 != 590 and px2 < 600:
                    drawpad.move(player,8,0)

    def collisionDetect(self):
        global drawpad
        global bricklist
        global direction
        global angle
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = drawpad.coords(ball)
        for brick in bricklist:
            bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
            if x1 >= bx1 and x2 <= bx2 and y1 >= by2 and y2 <= by1:
                return True
                drawpad.delete(brick)
                self.score = self.score + 5
                self.scoreTxt.config(text=str(self.score))

app = myApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: In the `collisionDetect(self)` if statement it is returning true without running the other 3 lines underneath the return. Could that be it?

Comment: Are you aware that the canvas has functions for determining which objects are overlapped by another object? You might find you can replace a lot of your collision detection with a call to the `find_overlapping` function of the canvas.