# Unpack Coordinates of Variable

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, collision-detection

So after asking about collision detection before, [Collision Detection in a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238253/collision-detection-in-a-list),
I added in the

```
 find_overlapping
```

function. The collision detection works fine but since I'm creating a brick breaker style game I have to change the direction variables depending on which side of the brick the ball hits. The brick that is hit is saved in the variable 'brick', but when I try to run the program an error comes up, "ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack". I'm guessing this means it's trying to find the coordinates of 'brick' but since there is no brick variable yet it can't run? Can someone please help explain.

```
overlap = drawpad.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2)
length = len(overlap)
if length > 1: 
     listPlace = overlap[1] - 3
     brick = bricklist[listPlace]
     drawpad.delete(brick)
     bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
     if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
            angle = -angle
     if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
            direction = -direction
```

I also rewrote the code to below, however I think I only complicated it because the same error message appeared.

```
overlap = drawpad.find_overlapping(x1,y1,x2,y2)
length = len(overlap)
if length > 1: 
      listPlace = overlap[1] - 3
      brick = bricklist[listPlace]
      drawpad.delete(brick)
      for x in bricklist:
            if x == brick: 
                bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(x)
                if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
                    angle = -angle
                if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
                    direction = -direction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the coordinates *before* you remove the object:

```
if length > 1: 
    listPlace = overlap[1] - 3
    brick = bricklist[listPlace]
    # Get the coordinates
    bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = drawpad.coords(brick)
    # Now delete it
    drawpad.delete(brick)
    if x1 <= bx1 or x2 >= bx2:
        angle = -angle
    if y1 <= by1 or by2 >= y2:
        direction = -direction
```

Comment: Thank you that definitely makes sense! I changed it but I still can't run it, the same error is still appearing? Am I still missing something?

Comment: Are you sure `brick` contains a tag that actually exists in `dropped` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

"ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack" means that you're doing something like the following, but the function is returning no results:

```
a,b,c,d = function(...)
```

You're asking python to "unpack" the result of the function and spread the results over four variables. This requires that the function actually return four values. The error message is telling you it's returning zero items. So the root cause of the error is that you're making a false assumption that the function always returns four values.

In your case you're calling `drawpad.coords(...)`. If it's returning zero results, that means the object you're trying to get the coordinates for doesn't exist. That means either that (a) you have a good reference for an object but that object has been deleted, or (b) your reference is bad.

You need to put some debug statements in to make sure that `brick` (or `x`) is what you think it is. You also need to make sure that you get the coordinates *before* you delete the object, because you can't get the coordinates for something that has been deleted.

Comment: Okay I changed the code so I could get the coordinates before I delete the brick, however I still have the same error. The brick list is global in the function but do I need to make all of the bricks themselves global too even though they're in the list or is that unnecessary/irrelevant. And I don't know how to put in debug statements so could you guide me with them or is there a simple explanation that you could link me to? Thank you!